# How can i plot the difference between two histograms? (Julia)

Tags: julia, histogram

So time ago i asked the same question here and someone answered just what i wanted!
Using `fit(histogram...)` and `weights` you can do it! (just like the picture below).

```
julia> using StatsBase, Random; Random.seed!(0);

julia> x1, x2 = rand(100), rand(100);

julia> h1 = fit(Histogram, x1, 0:0.1:1);

julia> h2 = fit(Histogram, x2, 0:0.1:1);

julia> using Plots

julia> p1 = plot(h1, α=0.5, lab="x1") ; plot!(p1, h2, α=0.5, lab="x2")

julia> p2 = bar(0:0.1:1, h2.weights - h1.weights, lab="diff")

julia> plot(p1, p2)
```

The problem is i can't use fit, i need to use `Histogram(...)`. And this one doesn't have `.weights`.
How can i do this using **Histogram** ?
This is what i'm using:

```
using Plots
using StatsBase   
h1 = histogram(Group1, bins= B, normalize =:probability, labels = "Group 1")
h2 = histogram(Group2 , bins= B, normalize =:probability, labels ="Group 2"))
```

[image]

Comment: could you pls make your code reproducible? And the question is about not using `fit` and you do not use it in your code already?

Comment: done! and i added the code i'm using for histograms.

Answer (score 3):

Technically there is no `Histogram` function in any common Julia package; perhaps you mean either the `Histogram` (capital h) *type* provided by StatsBase, or the `histogram` (lowercase h) function provided by Plots.jl? In either case though, the answer is "you can't".

If you mean `histogram` from Plots.jl there is unfortunately no practical way to access that underlying data. If you mean `Histogram` from StatsBase on the other hand, that only works with `fit` (it's a type, not a function that can be used on its own).

There are other histogram packages though if for any reason you cannot or do not want to use StatsBase and `fit`, including [FastHistograms.jl](https://github.com/Octogonapus/FastHistograms.jl) and [NaNStatistics.jl](https://github.com/brenhinkeller/NaNStatistics.jl), both of which are additionally somewhat faster than StatsBase for simple cases. So, for example

```
using NaNStatistics, Plots
a,b = rand(100), rand(100)
dx = 0.1
binedges = 0:dx:1
aw = histcounts(a, binedges)
bw = histcounts(b, binedges)
bar(binedges, aw-bw, label="difference", bar_width=dx)
```

[image: histogram diff example]